# Is it possible to upgrade/change iMac graphics card after purchase?

Tags: mac, graphics-card, imac

The title says it's all but for the sake of clarity: Is it possible to upgrade/change iMac graphics card after purchase by yourself (without authorized service)?

I would like to upgrade it to the newest Radeon (or NVidia if it's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. (It seems the cards need mac-specific bios/drivers)

[Here is a thorough discussion on the issue.](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=816107)

Comment: Thanks. A bit disappointing but what can you do :)